# waitForIdleStateSync method in PCRuntimeConfigurator is taking long time to respond

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I am using PCRuntimeConfigurator to generate a configuration by using customized methods. Some configurations are ok but some configuration are talking too long to respond. Upon investigating waitForIdleStateSync method is taking long time to respond. I have pasted Microsoft Learn page about the method.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamics/ax-2012/reference/jj827647(v=ax.60) .

Can anyone direct me how to solve the issue.

Thanks,
Vivek.

Comment: You haven't provided any real information to help solve the issue. You just said a technology you're using and that it's slow. If you can provide more information, you might help us help you. I would just guess kernel upgrade. You've also included `R2` and `R3` in your tags, so we don't even know what version you're using. There's `KB2969969` that addresses some slowness with `R2`

Comment: In Product Configuration model I have added new attributes. The old attributes  when used, they are fast .But when used new attributesis used it is taking time. The code is working from past one year , but the problem happened only in when using new attributes. There are around 300 attributes which i am using in runtime. Perhaps not related to R2 or R3 , because it is not entirely new problem and i can run some configs(old atributes) relatively fast.

Comment: Why haven't you clarified if you're using `R2` or `R3` yet? There's a performance hotfix for `R2` that I've mentioned. You should provide code or more info.

Comment: Can confirm that this is fast in R3, never used this in R2